# Bluetooth dealing iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

I have got a BeoPlay 7 bluetooth headphone. If I double press the headphone it dials the last person I spoke to on the phone. 
Is there anyway to disable this behaviour in iOS 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's a functionality which is built in iOS and is not customizable.